# How to create javafx application for windows XP

Tags: java, javafx, windows-xp

the subject matter is reflected in the title. I created the application with the help of jdk 1.8_144 using javafx. On Windows 10 x64, windows 7 x64 on this version of jdk all works well, but when I install this jdk on windows xp sp3 x32 the program window opens, but when I try to interact with it, it immediately closes.
I understand that Windows XP is a fairly old operating system, and there is no point in supporting it, but maybe someone has encountered such a problem and knows the solution to my problem. I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up something older like JDK6, which will have XP compatibility. I don't recommend running XP as it is a discontinued operating system since 2014 and there is a lot of vulnerabilities that will never be fixed

JavaFX doesn't come bundled with JDK6, you need to install it separately, instructions are available on Oracle's web site: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation_2-2-5/javafx-installation-windows.htm#BABJDGFJ

Comment: JDK6 doesn't have JavaFX.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't come bundled, see my updated answer, I still don't advise you to run XP in any computer.